# Center page vertically, make it scroll if bigger than screen

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple HTML page which will have content of unknown height. I want achieve following behavior:

**1) Content height < Screen height:** Make page centered vertically

**2) Content height > Screen height:** Display page with scrollbars and margin on both top and bottom

*Example:*

[image]

How can I do this with CSS? (or JS)

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the magic `flexbox` + a bit of jQuery code.

1. When the window height is taller than content size, `flexbox` can handle it all.
2. If the window height is shorter than content size, set the container to the normal `display:block;`.

```js
$(document).ready(myfunction);
$(window).on('resize', myfunction);

function myfunction() {
    var wh = $(window).height();
    var ch = $('.content').height();
    if (wh > ch) {
        $('.container').css('display', 'flex');
    } else {
        $('.container').css('display', 'block');
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}
.content {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
</div>
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ecjxb0y/)**

Comment: Thank you but I would like to display standard browser scrollbars of whole page, not inside the container...

Comment: I updated the answer, hope it all works now.

Comment: Thank you, your updated answer solves the problem!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is let's wrap the contents inside a `div` with an `id="content"`. This would have an `overflow: hidden`, so that the height will be calculated correctly.

```
<div id="content">
  <!-- Content -->
</div>
```

```css
#content {overflow: hidden; margin-top: 20px;}
```

Let's first dead-center the `#content`.

```css
.center #content {position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 25%; width: 50%;}
```

And you need to use jQuery or JavaScript to set the others. For now, I am using jQuery.

```
$(function () {
  if ($(window).height() > $("#content").height()) {
    // Content is lesser height than window.
    $("body").addClass("center");
    $("#content").css("margin-top", -$("#content").height()/2).css("overflow", "visible");
  }
});
```

Check out the following snippets for both:

```js
$(function () {
  if ($(window).height() > $("#content").height()) {
    // Content is lesser height than window.
    $("body").addClass("center");
    $("#content").css("margin-top", -$("#content").height()/2);
  }
});
```

```css
#content {overflow: hidden; margin-top: 20px;}
.center #content {position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 25%; width: 50%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut amet maxime praesentium minus facilis placeat temporibus quas. Minus fuga quia vel rerum, sit, nulla est magni unde maxime accusantium numquam.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis dolore amet voluptates consequatur enim quas natus et, nostrum quae, aliquam fugit tempora fuga ipsam at animi pariatur atque. Deleniti, expedita.</p>
</div>
```

Long Content:

```js
$(function () {
  if ($(window).height() > $("#content").height()) {
    // Content is lesser height than window.
    $("body").addClass("center");
    $("#content").css("margin-top", -$("#content").height()/2).css("overflow", "visible");
  }
});
```

```css
#content {overflow: hidden; margin-top: 20px;}
.center #content {position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 25%; width: 50%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut amet maxime praesentium minus facilis placeat temporibus quas. Minus fuga quia vel rerum, sit, nulla est magni unde maxime accusantium numquam.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis dolore amet voluptates consequatur enim quas natus et, nostrum quae, aliquam fugit tempora fuga ipsam at animi pariatur atque. Deleniti, expedita.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut amet maxime praesentium minus facilis placeat temporibus quas. Minus fuga quia vel rerum, sit, nulla est magni unde maxime accusantium numquam.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis dolore amet voluptates consequatur enim quas natus et, nostrum quae, aliquam fugit tempora fuga ipsam at animi pariatur atque. Deleniti, expedita.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut amet maxime praesentium minus facilis placeat temporibus quas. Minus fuga quia vel rerum, sit, nulla est magni unde maxime accusantium numquam.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis dolore amet voluptates consequatur enim quas natus et, nostrum quae, aliquam fugit tempora fuga ipsam at animi pariatur atque. Deleniti, expedita.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it almost works - take a look here: http://vzpominkomat.com/micipus/test.php - short content is ok, but if I make it longer (tried to set font-size to 30px for example), first paragraph is partially hidden.

Comment: @milano I guess that is because of `overflow: hidden`. We can remove it after you have resized.

Comment: I tried to add css({ overflow: 'auto' }) after resize but it doesn't help...

Comment: You need to add `.css("overflow", "visible");` in the JavaScript. I have added that. Have a look now.

Comment: It¨s still the same. It looks like this: http://goo.gl/hDA6KO

Comment: @milano Are you doing it after checking the height?

Comment: Take a look at site where I try it live: http://vzpominkomat.com/micipus/test.php

Comment: Yes, I can see that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91973/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-milano).

Comment: Thank you very much Kumar, Pangloss' answer solves the problem.