# CSS ONLY vertically center with scroll even when child is bigger than screen

Tags: css

I have a similar problem as described here:
[Center page vertically, make it scroll if bigger than screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067927/center-page-vertically-make-it-scroll-if-bigger-than-screen)
however I'm trying to find a pure CSS only solution, not involving JS.

I have a fixed containers defined like that:

```css
.parent{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
.child{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
}
```

It's well centered (as expected) when child is smaller than parent/viewport height. The problem is when child's height is greater then parent's height. Let's say parent has height 1000 px and child's height is 1600 px.

With above styles applied, I can scroll child (as expected) but not all the way to its top. The top of child is hidden and not possible to scroll to it.
What I want to achieve is to be able to scroll the child all the way to its top border.

The main question is if it's possible to achieve that with CSS only?

Comment: Please, add HTML to your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
    display: flex; /* Use this proparty */
    align-items: center; /* For Center align */
    justify-content: center; /* For Center align */
    overflow: auto; /* For auto scroll */
    padding: 20px; /* This is only for spacing */
}
.child {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 560px; /* Use max-width instant of width in responsive  it's help you for better view */
    max-height: 100%; /* Use max-height instant of heiht in responsive it's tack auto height from text/content  */
}
```

```html
<!-- Parent Div start Here -->
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Parent Div ends Here -->
```